# Excel Intersect Method in VBS

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am trying to find if a cell exists within a range. I copied method found in VBA code and tried to convert it to vbs. But it throws:

> Unable to get the Intersect property of the Application class
>
> Line (12): "Set Intersect = ExcelApp.Intersect(FirstRow,MergedRange)".""

My code is below:

```
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Visible = True
Set MergedRange = ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Set FoundObj = ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Columns("C").Find("purchase invoice")
Set FirstRow = ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Range(Replace(FoundObj.Address,"C","A"))
Set Intersect = ExcelApp.Intersect(FirstRow,MergedRange)
```

I also used `ExcelApp.Application.Intersect` and that also didn't work.
Let me know whats wrong with the code.

Comment: I'm not at a computer to check, but I believe `Intersect ` is both a many parameter function (`ParamArray`) and expects `Range` arguments, not `Object` as you need for VBScript.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't include opening or creating a workbook

Comment: @MarkHurd But I am passing Range arguments only, variable Merged Range and First Row are both Range Objects..Also if its a argument error, why is it throwing "Unable to get the Intersect Property"?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your code is mostly OK.

I strongly recommend not to use a function name (`Intersect(...)`) as the name for a variable (`Set Intersect = ...`). Copying all relevant lines (`Set ...`) to Excel VBA (2013), removing all preceeding `ExcelApp.` you get a compile error bemourning exactly this. Renaming variable Intersect to something else produces a perfectly working code at my end (VBA though ...).

Should renaming your variable not cure the issue, examine further if all your arguments to the Intersect function really are ranges .... better to `Dim ... As Range` them upfont to catch conditions where e.g. the `Find` doesn't true up.